# Actually easy PHP IF-statement on array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I'm working on a little thing for uni. 
However, the following is a small problem in the whole thing, which keeps me from progressing.

I read in a file containing the data on the names and want to sort it depending on the different details using if-statements so far. This is where the problem occurs:

```
for($i ;$i < count($file); $i++){
    if($i>0) {
        $data = explode(",", $file[$i]);
        echo $data[0] . $data[1] . $data[2] . $data[3] . $data[4];  //this works
        ?><br /><?php

        //The following one works too.
        if($data[0] == "Ann"){
            echo $data[0];
            ?><br /><br /><?php
        }

        // All these don't work
        if($data[3] == "californien") {
            echo 'Name: '. $data[0] . ', Occurences: '. $data[4];
            ?><br /><?php   
        }

        if($data[2] == "20-30"){
            echo $data[0];
            ?><br /><?php
        }

        if($data[1] == "w"){
            echo $data[0];
            ?><br /><?php
        }
    }
}
```

A sample from the csv file looks like this:

(Name, sex, year interval, state, occurences)

```
Mary, w, 10-20, californien, 88
```

Just using echo on some of the $data array elements works fine.
Using the if-statement on the name ($data[0]) works, too.
But if I wanna use any of the other parts like the interval, state sex, or occurrences it doesn't show anything at all.

I guess and hope it's just a small thing I didn't notice.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Can you post what's the result if you do `print_r($data)` after `$data = explode(",", $file[$i]);`. Would definitely help a lot.

Comment: Not that it is wrong, but I would write `echo '<br>';` instead of `?><br /><?php`.

Comment: Also may there is some  starting or trailing spaces there in your other columns data so use `trim()` like:- `if(!empty(trim($data[3])) &&  trim($data[3]) == "californien") {` and so on for othhers

Comment: Probably an extra space after each comma. If that's the problem explode(", ",... should work.

Comment: `[space]something` !== `something`

Comment: why don't you use `echo "<br />";` instead of `?><br /><?php` ?

Comment: The field delimiter isn't a simple comma, but a comma followed by a space.

Comment: @Katastrophenmagnet Your code could benefit from many, many refinements, can you tell me in plain English how you are actually intending to filter and what you want to output?  Do you you only want to show the `Name` and `Occurences` if a series of criteria are met?  Please update your question to explain you true goal (and perhaps give us 3 rows of data that will reflect what should and should not be filtered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this input shown by you:-

```
(Name, sex, year interval, state, occurences)

Mary, w, 10-20, californien, 88
```

It seems you have white-spaces in your values.So you can resolve it like below:-

1.`explode()` with`", "`(comma with space) :-

```
$data = explode(", ", $file[$i]);
```

2.Or use `trim()` like below:-

```
if(trim($data[3]) == "californien") { // and so-on for others
```

A clean code need to be like below-

```
for($i ;$i < count($file); $i++){
    if($i>0) {
        $data = explode(", ", $file[$i]);

       //exploded with comma and spaces but confirm again through trim()

        if(trim($data[0]) == "Ann"){
            echo $data[0]."<br/><br/>";
        }

        if(trim($data[1]) == "w"){
            echo $data[0]."<br />";
        }

        if(trim($data[2]) == "20-30"){
            echo $data[0]."<br />";
        }

        if(trim($data[3]) == "californien") {
            echo 'Name: '. $data[0] . ', Occurences: '. $data[4]."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize that the white spaces were the problem. You also suggested a great solution!

Comment: @Katastrophenmagnet  glad to help you:):)